# Update label text only use a part of the given text

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# and trying without success to update a label text after a http request from an API.
I am doing it like below:

```
 private void buttonGenerateKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var apiKey = getApiKey();
    Console.WriteLine("Your API Key: " + apiKey); //-> Your API Key: Knh4dH4d8rtWfgXr5
    labelApiKeyText.Text = "Your API Key: " + apiKey; //-> Your API Key:
    Console.WriteLine("Label Content: " + labelApiKeyText.Text); //-> Your API Key: Knh4dH4d8rtWfgXr5
    labelApiKeyText.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen;
    labelApiKeyText.Refresh();
}

// --- Get an API Key
private string getApiKey()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:61128/StationService.svc/");
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("key").Result;
    var ApiKeyString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var ApiKey = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(ApiKeyString.Result);
    return ApiKey;
}
```

I can see the right text in the console, but the label is only showing "Your API Key:"

Even after trying to use a BackgroundWorker i didn't succeed. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that this handler is hit? the click event, I mean?

Comment: @st_stefanov Yes, `Console.WriteLine("Your API Key: " + apiKey);` is showing in the console

Comment: Can you please add one more line after this Console.WriteLine and there write the current value of labelApiKey.Textl. Tell us what it is.

Comment: `GetAsync("key")` is not going to return anything, you'll need to pass the uri to the http client. And use `async/await` with blocking with `.Result`

Comment: Yeah, good point JSteward, but he says that in the console the value is fine, so we suppose that the ApiKey variable has a value.

Comment: @JSteward Its returning something. You can see it with the `Console.WriteLine("Your API Key: " + apiKey);`. Hope you are not the one downvoting the question.

Comment: Were you able to output the current text of the Label in the console? If you can't display the text that will tell us the issue...

Comment: @st_stefanov `Console.WriteLine("Label Content: " + labelApiKeyText.Text);`  is showing the right text `Your API Key: Knh4dH4d8rtWfgXr5`  in the console.

Comment: Ok, so the label value is updated, only it does not refresh on your form. I had issue in the past if I try to update control property from another thread, but I think this is not the issue in your case.

Comment: @st_stefanov you are right. But i don't know why the form is not updated?

Comment: @st_stefanov Thanks for your help. I will continue to check what is wrong

Comment: The Async call might be the issue, giving the control to another thread, but I am not able to confirm or explain better...

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following, see if it helps.

```
private async string getApiKey()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:61128/StationService.svc/");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("key");
    if(response==null)
    {
        // something went wrong
    }
    var ApiKeyString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var ApiKey = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(ApiKeyString);
    return ApiKey;
}
```